# Live USB installation hanging on startup - Vivid, Acer Aspire V

Tags: boot, system-installation, usb, 15.04, acer

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 15.04 and it keeps hanging at the point where it says

```
Starting Wait for Plymouth boot screen to Quit
```

I've tried two different iso downloads (md5 is correct) and two different memory sticks. Yet, scanning the disk says that there are errors in two files (with both sticks and both iso's).

I'm really at a loss as to why this might happen. Any suggestions?

*Edit:* 14.04.2 seems to work fine (except for click pad, network and graphics issues). I'd like to know if this is a hardware problem, as when it comes to upgrading it would be a real problem if later versions are not compatible with my hardware.

Answer (score 1):

To install the newest version of Ubuntu from Live USB I used a program that installed Ubuntu on the USB first and made it bootable

Link: [This will install the newest version of Ubuntu on your USB drive for you](http://www.pendrivelinux.com)